# In heads-up play, can player A, who has 150 left, all-in if player B all-in at 100? Or he can only call?

Tags: all-in

Player A has 150 left while player B has 100. Player B all-in first. Can player A all-in too of he can only call?

Answer (score 1):

Both actions would result in the same outcome. If the lower stack is 100, neither player will put more than 100 chips into the pot.

Comment: Thanks! So literally neither player can't do the action "All-in"?

Comment: @SimoXing both can but they'd be playing for 100 chips, not for 150.

Answer (score 1):

are there more then two players, if only 2 players this question is mute there is no point putting all the chips. if there is another player that will need to cover the raise to proceed, then of course the player can go all, in

Comment: Thanks! There are only two players left. I searched TDA and it says whenever you face a bet you can all-in. So not sure about it.

Comment: if one is not sure of the opponents stack size they should just announce the all in or ask for a count of the players stack